Optimizing a Dynamic Fitness Function with Differential Evolution Across Multiple Time Steps

I have a dynamic fitness function f(x,t) that I need to optimize using Differential Evolution (DE). Here, t represents time steps within the range [0, 8759] and x is a vector of decision variables.
For a fixed t (e.g., t=0), DE converges after about 1000 iterations. However, I want to find x values that solve f(x,t) = 0 for all t values without running DE separately for each time step.
Here's my current approach for t=0:

Initialize the DE algorithm by creating a population of 100 solution vectors using Latin Hypercube Sampling.
Calculate the fitness value for each solution vector in this population (i.e., f(x_0, t=0), f(x_1, t=0), f(x_2, t=0), etc.).
Determine the best individual and continue the algorithm through several generations using the usual selection/mutation/crossover operations.

To extend this approach to other t values, my idea was to:

Change the fitness function's t value randomly for each generated trial solution vector.
If a previously calculated x value solves f(xprev, trand) = 0, then I remove that random t from the list of all possible t values.

My goal is to map all possible t values with different x vectors. However, I am facing difficulties in adjusting the fitness scores of the solution vectors because they are valid only for specific t values and change when t changes.
Questions:

How can I effectively modify the fitness function or DE approach to handle dynamic t values?
Are there any strategies or modifications to the DE algorithm that can help solve f(x,t) = 0 for the entire range of t values without running DE individually for each t?

Any insights or suggestions for handling this dynamic optimization problem would be greatly appreciated.
